# How can I make the user not able to enter anything, but the user can press enter to go to the next step of the program?

Tags: java, input, terminal, java.util.scanner

I want to make a program that has a part where the user cannot input anything, but the user can press enter to progress. Also, it doesn't show the input. Here's how it should go:

```java
System.out.println("Welcome to Earth. Press enter to continue.");
//The code that doesn't accept input, except enter
System.out.println("Oops. Program has ended. Please wait for 100 years. Thank you!");
```

I tried doing it by only making the program "move on", if my string is equal to "".

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        int x = 0;
        while(x == 0) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Earth. press enter to continue.");
        input = scan.nextLine();
        if(input.equals("")) {
            x = 1;
        }
        if(x == 1) {
        System.out.println("OOps. Program has ended. Please wait for 100 years. Thank you!");
        }
        }
    }
```

The result is just "Welcome to Earth. press enter to continue." repeating over and over again if it's `input` is not equal to "".

Comment: That's some what difficult to accomplish.  One solution would be to supply your own `InputStream` which would act as a proxy to the system stdin which would consume the input you didn't want to display.  Another solution might be to do the opposite, use a `PrintStream` as a proxy to the stdout and filter out content you didn't want to display.  A more complex solution would be to make use of a curses API wrapper, but that could end up as a mess

Comment: Oh... So... It's possible, but super hard for a beginner like me?

Comment: More or less, but, if you're up to a challenge ;)

Comment: I'm new. Should I finish MOOC first before learning this? Is there not another way? Like using a library?

Comment: I'm not aware of any library which would provide this functionality that doesn't use curses (which is system library found on linux/unix systems).  Java's console I/O is pretty basic to start with, so the functionality you're trying to achieve will require you to take over, either in part or fully, the existing functionality, so, no, not "simple".  I'd focus on building your skills and accomplishing your core goal and then come back to it as a "nice to have" feature

Comment: Oof. Okay. Thank you so much.